# Multiple integral and area of a sphere

Tags: real-analysis, integration, proof-explanation, multiple-integral, spheres

Let $A_{n-1}$ be the area of the sphere in $\Bbb R^n$ given by $S_{n-1}=\{ (x_1,\dots,x_n) \in \Bbb R^n \lvert \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2=1 \}.$ We have that the area of a sphere of radius $r$ is given by $r^{n-1}A_{n-1}$.

A step in a computation says that $$\int_{\Bbb R^n}e^{-\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}dx_1 \dots dx_n = A_{n-1} \int_0^{+ \infty}e^{-r^2}r^{n-1}dr $$

There is obviously a change of variables with $r$ but I don't see why exactly this equality holds, can someone explain ?

Comment: Briefly, map $S^{n-1}\times(0,\infty)$ to Euclidean space by $(x, r) \mapsto rx$. You might search this site for some variant of "$n$-dimensional spherical coordinates integral" and see if any of the hits provide useful details.

Comment: You don't need a specific coordinate system to follow this. Choose any coordinate system $(u_1, \dots, u_{n-1})$ of $S_{n-1}$ and make the coordinate conversion from $x = (x_1, \dots, x_n)$ to $(u_1, \dots, u_{n-1}, r)$ where $r = \sqrt{\sum_i x_i^2}$ and the $u_i$ are the $S_{n-1}$ coordinates of the point $u = \frac xr$. The integral on the right consists of the $r$-dependent factors of the converted integrand, while the remainder of the integrand is just $\int_{S_{n-1}} 1\,|du| = A_{n-1}$. Note that this only works because your original integrand is a function of $r$ alone.